# Automated Screenshots using Powershell and Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell

the main goal of this case is to automatically create screenshots of the visualisation in the production hall in defined times. In production hall there´s a display where´s running a visualisation about productivity and it refreshes every 30 secs.

I´m setting up an automated method of creating screenshots at defined times because the display is hard to manage manually only remotely. At least the screenshots should be saved to a network drive.

*There´s is one bug or maybe admin privileges but on my personal PC I can do fine screenshots with task scheduler. On remote pc where the visualisation is running the script with task scheduler is doing just a "**black window**" image.*

What I have already tried is downloading a PowerShell script which fits every of the customer´s needs. The script is creating a screenshot of the whole background. When I tried the script with task scheduler on my PC because I needed to set up 2 different times for the day to generate a screenshot without any manual manipulation (like logging into remote pc then hitting the prtscrn button and save it to a file). This script should do this automatically by task scheduler.

> **Attempt 1** Here´s a demonstration where the script was started
>   manually.  If the script is started manually with powershell (admin
>   privileges) creates just a small resolution of active window (even if
>   the Screen definition is coded for parameter "Area" and it has defined
>   the Width, Height, Left and Top positions for fit-screen) (number 3)
>
> **Attempt 2** If the script is being started by task scheduler at defined
>   time, there comes a pop-up powershell window (because of -windowStyle
>   hidden because of additional argument) (no. 2)
>
> **Attempt 3** If the script is ran manually from the PowerShell ISE editor
>   than the screenshot is generated perfectly and fits for the whole
>   resolution (4K) no changes in the code. (no. 1)

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l763.jpg

The code for this powershell script is:

```
    Function Get-ScreenShot
    {   
        [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Directory',                 PositionalBinding=$false)]
        Param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='File')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$False, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$False)]
    [ValidateScript({$_  -match "\.(bmp|gif|jpg|png|wmf)$"})]
    [string]$FullName,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Directory')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$False, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$False)]
    [string]$Directory,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Directory')]
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [ValidateSet('bmp','gif','jpg','png','wmf')]
    [String]$Format='png',

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Directory')]
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [ValidateScript({$_ -ge 0})]
    [int]$DurationInSeconds=0,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Directory')]
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [ValidateScript({$_ -ge 0})]
    [int]$IntervalInSeconds=0,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [ValidateSet('VirtualScreen','WorkingArea')]
    [String]$Area='WorkingArea',

    [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [Switch]$Beep
)


Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
# Gather Screen resolution information
#$Screen = [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::VirtualScreen
#$Screen = [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::WorkingArea
$Screen = [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::$Area
$Width = $Screen.Width
$Height = $Screen.Height
$Left = $Screen.Left
$Top = $Screen.Top
$TimeElapsed = 0
$IsTimeStampedFileName = $false
if ($FullName)
{
    $Directory = Split-Path -Path $FullName -Parent
    $HasExtension = $FullName -match "\.(?<Extension>\w+)$"
    if ($HasExtension)
    {
        $Format = $Matches['Extension']
    }
    New-Item -Path $Directory -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null
}
elseif ($Directory)
{
    New-Item -Path $Directory -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null
    $FullName = Join-Path -Path $Directory -ChildPath $((get-date -f yyyyMMddTHHmmss)+".$Format")
    $IsTimeStampedFileName = $true
}
else
{
    $Directory = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('MyPictures')
    Write-Verbose "Target directory not specified we use [$Directory]"
    $FullName = Join-Path -Path $Directory -ChildPath $((get-date -f yyyyMMddTHHmmss)+".$Format")
    $IsTimeStampedFileName = $true
}

switch ($Format)
{
    'bmp' { $Imageformat= [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Bmp; }
    'gif' { $Imageformat= [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Gif; }
    'jpg' { $Imageformat= [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Jpeg; }
    'png' { $Imageformat= [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Png; }
    'wmf' { $Imageformat= [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Wmf; }
}

do 
{
    # Create bitmap using the top-left and bottom-right bounds
    $Bitmap = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Bitmap -ArgumentList $Width, $Height

    # Create Graphics object
    $Graphic = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($Bitmap)

    # Capture screen
    $Graphic.CopyFromScreen($Left, $Top, 0, 0, $Bitmap.Size)

    # Save to file
    $Bitmap.Save($FullName, $Imageformat) 
    Write-Verbose -Message "[$(get-date -Format T)] Screenshot saved to $FullName"
    if ($Beep)
    {
        [console]::beep()
    }

    if (($DurationInSeconds -gt 0) -and ($IntervalInSeconds -gt 0))
    {
        Write-Verbose "[$(get-date -Format T)] Sleeping $IntervalInSeconds seconds ..."
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $IntervalInSeconds
        $TimeElapsed += $IntervalInSeconds
    }
    if ($IsTimeStampedFileName)
    {
        $FullName = Join-Path -Path $Directory -ChildPath $((get-date -f yyyyMMddTHHmmss)+".$Format")
    }
} While ($TimeElapsed -lt $DurationInSeconds) 
    }    
    #endregion

    Clear-Host
    New-Alias -Name New-ScreenShoot -Value Get-ScreenShot -ErrorAction                 SilentlyContinue
    #Get-ScreenShot -Verbose
    Get-ScreenShot -Directory 'C:\temp' -Format jpg -DurationInSeconds 300 -        IntervalInSeconds 10 -Area WorkingArea -Beep -Verbose
    #Get-ScreenShot -FullName 'c:\temp\screenshot.wmf' -Verbose
```

The code for automatic powershell task run is defined directly in task scheduler ("task"->properties->actions-> Start program is "PowerShell.exe" and additional argument to run this script in the background is used an additional argument "-windowStyle hidden C:/path..." ´cause the idea was to create screenshot automatically of the whole visualisation which is on a 4K display in production without seeing any additional windows started.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4Aya.jpg

sry for not posting images, not enough rep for that :-)

Comment: [1] the ISE is a GUI app - so it loads all the needed winform stuff. you likely need to add that to the top of your script. [2] task scheduler usually runs code via a specific account - the system, a specified user account, or "the current user". the only one that will be able to interact with your display is the "current user" account ... so ... what account is running the script?

Comment: The account what is running the script is probably just a user for which I have access. Noticed that there is another "administrator" account but I have no access for it. Maybe I will try to run under " administrator" ?

What should be exactly be in the top of the script that ISE uses ?

Comment: i just tested your code and it works from the Powershell.exe console ... so all the needed stuff is already being loaded. please ignore the `[1]` comment. [*blush*] ///// you need to run the code with the same account that is running the display - otherwise the screen capture will be capturing the wrong "screen".

Comment: Interesting, I thought that accounts are there for just like account with limited privileges. Did not even consider that can capture wrong screen, hm. I dont know exactly wha to do cause the account that I´m using has administrator privileges and it´s configured for that device. At least there is one another separately "administrator" account. Should I try the 2nd account ?

Comment: Usually you can't do stuff in the "user space" remotely. Running the script in task Scheduler using the current logged on user works though.

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure:**

1. The scheduled task is run by the user, that will be logged into the PC when the task is triggered.
2. The task is only run, if the user is logged on.

I highlighted the two settings in the screenshot below:

[image: Scheduled task settings general tab]

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same issue.
I have found the answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/872335/powershell-script-will-run-but-screen-capture-not-completed-why). The problem in my case was the same as explained there: the option "Run whether the user is logged in or not" was selected.